# ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired, Unable to open Monitor Sessions tab

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to drop a table but this comes up constantly.

When I try to open "Monitor sessions" in order to kill it this comes up.

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Vendor code 942

I googled the problem and I tried recommended solutions.

I tried this solution

```
select object_name, s.sid, s.serial#, p.spid 
from v$locked_object l, dba_objects o, v$session s, v$process p
where l.object_id = o.object_id and l.session_id = s.sid and s.paddr = p.addr;
```

But I get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

I also tried

```
SELECT
    O.OBJECT_NAME,
    S.SID,
    S.SERIAL#,
    P.SPID,
    S.PROGRAM,
    SQ.SQL_FULLTEXT,
    S.LOGON_TIME
FROM
    V$LOCKED_OBJECT L,
    DBA_OBJECTS O,
    V$SESSION S,
    V$PROCESS P,
    V$SQL SQ
WHERE
    L.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
    AND L.SESSION_ID = S.SID
    AND S.PADDR = P.ADDR
    AND S.SQL_ADDRESS = SQ.ADDRESS;
```

But the same thing, "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

How to proceed?

Comment: ORA-00054 means that someone/something is holding that table so - until they COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) - you can't drop it. ORA-00942 means that table you're trying to access doesn't exist (as error says itself). Are you sure you have privileges to work with all tables/views in the FROM clause?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably to GRANT a "SELECT" on these table as sysdba:

```
GRANT privileges ON object TO user;
```

privileges:  SELECT
object : Your table name
user : Your username